# Change the style of specific items inside ngFor

Tags: html, angular, angular5

I have a set of icons that are displayed using `ngFor` like this:

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let category of categories" (click)="selected(category)" [selected]="category.selected" [matTooltip]="category.name">
      <mat-icon id="iconBar"> {{category.icon}} </mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
```

and I am trying to change the color of one specific icon on a button press, my trial is to have this function executes when the button is pressed:

```
recolorRequired(){


  var loopedIcon = document.getElementById("iconBar");
  console.log(loopedIcon.textContent);
  var requiredIcon = loopedIcon.textContent;

  //recolor

}
```

The result of `console.log(loopedIcon.textContent);` is the first icon only, from my understanding that because I am using same id for multiple elements? is there a way I can obtain information about the whole icon collection from ngFor?

Comment: Do you want to change the background color? Does the color depend on the `selected` flag of the category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea it is because you are using an id in a loop, id is usually not meant to be used on multiple items, you can use a class instead.

```
<mat-chip *ngFor="let category of categories" (click)="selected(category)" [selected]="category.selected" [matTooltip]="category.name">
      <mat-icon class="iconBar"> {{category.icon}} </mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
```

your function becomes

```
recolorRequired(){


  var iconBars = document.getElementsByClassName("iconBar");
  //iconBars will be an array of elements who has iconBar as class
  //loop through iconBars and find the element you want

  //recolor

}
```

Comment: but you can not do something like that in the loop `iconBars[i].style` :/

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: No thanks all I needed to cast it as HTMLELEMENT, thank you for your help.